# Validation of Time

Tags: c#, javascript, datetime, validation

I am trying to validate time entry. `ArrTime` is the time entered by the user from the UI. I am trying to make it so that when a user attempts to add a time, it must be between 8:45 and 17:30. Is there any thing wrong with my code? I am not very good at JavaScript so I have a feeling it is that, but if you can help me at all I will be very grateful.

Here are all the parts of code that are involved in validation:

**JavaScript**

```
  timeValid: function () {
    var s = $(this).val();

    if ($(this).required()) {
        var arrTime = new ArrTime(s);

        var startTime = new Date(0001, 01, 01, 08, 46, 00, 00);
        var endTime = new Date(9999, 12, 366, 17, 30, 00, 00);

        if (arrTime > startTime) {
            $(this).removeClass("error");
            return true;
        }
        else {
            validation.showError("Invalid", $(this).attr("name"));
            $(this).addClass("error");
        }

        if (!isNaN(arrTime)) {
            if (arrTime >= ArrTime.parse(new ArrTime().toTimeString())) {
                $(this).removeClass("error");
                return true;
            }
            else {
                validation.showError("Invalid", $(this).attr("name"));
                $(this).addClass("error");
                return false;
            }
        }
        else {
            validation.showError("Required", $(this).attr("name"));
            $(this).addClass("error");
            return false;
        }
    }
    else return false;
},
```

**JavaScript**

```
var deferrend = $.Deferred();

    if (new Date(dateTo) > new Date()) {
        deferrend = confirmation.ask("Are you sure you want to add a future absence?");
    } else {
        deferrend.resolveWith(true);
    }

    if (new Date(arrTime) > new Date()) {
        deferrend = confirmation.ask("Are you sure this is the correct time for being late?");
    }
    else {
        deferrend.resolveWith(true);
    }
```

**C#**

```
public static bool IsValidTime(this string s, out string error)
    {
        error = String.Empty;

        if (s.Required())
        {
            TimeSpan outTime;
            TimeSpan startTime = new TimeSpan(8, 46, 0);
            TimeSpan endTime = new TimeSpan(17, 30, 0);

            if (TimeSpan.TryParse(s, out outTime))
                if (outTime >= startTime && outTime <= endTime)
                    return true;
                else
                {
                    error = "Invalid";
                    return false;
                }
        }
        else
        {
            error = "Required";
            return false;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
    if (new Date(arrTime) > new Date()) {
        deferrend = confirmation.ask("Are you sure this is the correct time for being late?");
    }
    else {
        deferrend.resolveWith(true);
    }
```

Comment: You can remove every 'return false;' and only put it at the end of each method. You could also extract the error message operations to one single method, with the message as parameter.

Answer (score 1):

I would refactor conceptually and introduce a reusable `TimeRange` object with methods to check for inclusion:

```
class TimeRange : Range<DateTime>{

    bool Includes(DateTime other){...}
    bool Includes(TimeRange other){...}
    bool Includes(string other){...}

}
```

In this case, if `Includes` returns false, you have a validation error.